# Bulk Find/Replace Across Multiple Files

Tags: xml, replace, find, manifest, xml-editor

I am trying to modify a QTIv2.1 package, and need to replace thousands of strings from one value to another across 50+ imsmanifest.xml files. Is there a simple way to find the value (example: LA.R.3.4.b) and replace with new value in the same string (example: B190A18A-410B-4ACE-B5DB-04159F2949D1). This needs to be done for approximately 17,000 strings across 50+ XML files.

[Showing unedited string with default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44fmJ.png)

[Showing edited string with GUID replacing previous value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jb6t.png)

I am looking for a relatively quick way to find/replace values across all files at once, and then save the manifest files according to their properly nested folder location.

Is this possible or am looking at life too optimistically? If it is possible, what is the best XML editor or process to use for this process? Thank you for any help or advice.

I have tried a simple Find and Replace tool across Notepad++ and Oxygen XML Editor but this is too time consuming and would take too long to individually Find/Replace single values.

Comment: Your example needs more explanation

Comment: I've added example screenshots of the metadata

Comment: The task takes three steps 1) Open an xml file 2) make changes 3) save file.  The OS performs steps 1 & 3 and cannot be made quicker.  Step 2 depends on the editor.  Notepad++ is very quick so I do not think you can speed up this step.

Comment: I failed to mention the values searched are different and up to 17,000 variants, and the replacement value is a correlated GUID found in another table. So it's a lot of tedious back and forth searching, correlating, and then manually entering. Just trying to find out any ways to automate the work outside of a macro, which doesn't seem to do the job very accurately.

Comment: https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/25.1/ug-editor/topics/custom-refactoring-operations.html might help.